# How does Meteor decide the order of HTML elements?

Tags: meteor

> Meteor parses all of the HTML files in your app folder and identifies
>   three top-level tags: `<head>`, `<body>`, and `<template>`. Everything
>   inside any `<head>` tags is added to the head section of the HTML sent
>   to the client, and everything inside `<body>` tags is added to the body
>   section, just like in a regular HTML file.

My question is, if I have `a.html`:

```
<body><h1>Hello</h1></body>
```

and `b.html`:

```
<body><h1>Goodbye</h1></body>
```

How does Meteor figure out the order of elements to load?

Comment: Meteor's [file load order](https://guide.meteor.com/structure.html#load-order), I suppose. It is not generally a good idea to add stuff directly to the `body` from multiple files this way.

Comment: As MasterAM said: you don't want to do this: you should have one `<head>` and one `<body>` file, and then Template files you insert where you want to with `{{>template_name}}`